# Why not execute scp command on centos 6?

Tags: scp

my server ip 192.168.3.247

I want use scp.

and I try

`scp root@192.168.3.248:/root/disk.image/newversion/`

but not execute scp

```
usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
       [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
       [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

why not execute scp command on centos 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it like:

```
scp -r root@192.168.3.248:/root/disk.image/newversion/ .
```

Directories need to be copied *recursively* and you also need a target